# cruiser chainring

Tags: chainring

I have been urged by my physio to give up the mountain bike and only ride a cruiser. I would like to do some rides that are longer. I find the gears too slow for longer rides on the cruiser and wonder if I should change the teeth on the front chainring. the teeth numbers are presently 32/42 Any suggestions on the best approach to make for a better ride? I live on the prairies, No hills in sight so don't need a wide variation.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about the bike. "Cruiser" used generically refers to a one speed bike, usually with a one piece crank and a coaster brake. If that was what you had then the simple thing is a smaller cog and go down some links. But you have a double so it's not clear what sort of bike this is.

Comment: Seems to be odd advise from a physio (therapist ?)   Maybe you need a road bike ?

Comment: @Criggie: If I were in OP's place I'd look for another physio.

Comment: Assuming this is actually about having an upright riding position to prevent hunching forward or weight on wrists, there are lots of options for bikes like that that aren't "cruisers" by normal definition, e.g., https://www.linusbike.com/products/dutchi-7i

Comment: Sorry my definition wasn't right on a cruiser .it is an upright bike needed because of hip issues  and  I need to get away from the smaller hip rotation on a mountain bike. My bike has 18 speed  similar to the linus bike Its a hawahara shasta  model  but I find the  speed is too slow on the 42 teeth  of the chainring and unsure of the science but would it help to get a higher number. My mountain bike  has 48 teeth which suits my style of riding which  would it make my ride more enjoyable  i.e. get me out riding  if it was similar to what I am used to.